# DC-to-DC converter is giving weird output voltages

Tags: dc, lithium-ion

I am having an issue with an XL6009.

[image]

Basically I have 5v USB input to a TP4056 lithium charger which charges a single 3.7 lithium battery. Also from the output terminals of the TP4056 I am going into an XL6009 to step the voltage up to 5v to power an arduino. I use the pot on the XL6009 to get to 5v and this works perfectly when I have the USB plugged in.

But then I unplug the USB so that I am running solely on the 3.7v battery the output from the XL6009 goes up to around 39V. If I plug the USB in again it drops back down to 5v. The only load I have across the output of the XL6009 is a multimeter.
I understand that the XL6009 should deliver a 5v output regardless of a varying input voltage as long as it is within range.
I dont have much experience with these so I am betting I am doing something wrong but would like some help to point me in the right direction.

thanks
Sos

Comment: Provide a schematic of how you connected your components. Also, what is your load on the DC-DC converter?

Comment: Sorry sure. I have added a basic diagram. The only load I have on the dc-dc converter is a multimeter.

Comment: DC-DC converters often need a minimum load to stay within specifications. What does the datasheet of your converter say about minimum loads?

Comment: The TP4056 is designed to charge a lithium battery, but not to drive a DC to DC converter as well.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks. I had a quick check and I couldn't see anything to be honest. For my own understanding, wouldn't a multimeter present a load to the converter.

Comment: Hi Finbarr. I believe the newer version of TP4056 can charge the battery and provide power to a load. There is a B-,B+ and an OUT+ and OUT- for the load.

Comment: @SpeedOfSpin A multimeter on voltage measure mode is a very very light load. Easily 10 000 times smaller than a typical minimum load. You can try adding, say, a 470Ω resistor as load and see if the situation improves.

Comment: I attached a 1k resistor and that didn't make any difference. What I did try was to swap the battery out for a charged one and the output was then a steady 5v. If I put the battery back in and let it charge for an hour or so then the output was also a steady 5v. It seems as though using a battery that is in a discharged state causes the problem.